# Question about solution spaces of linear homogeneous differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm re-reading a book on introduction to linear algebra, that (I think) I used to understand. The book doesn't define the solution space, just relates solving equations to it. I'm assuming;

A second order linear homogeneous differential equation has a solution,

f(x) = g(x) + h(x)

and there is a solution space associated with that equation, where

f = a.g + b.h, and g,h span the space

Do the set of vectors of the solution space correspond to the **same** differential equation but with different Initial conditions ?

If the vectors don't correspond to the same equation can you explain to me what the solution space is then?

Comment: Yes, they correspond to the same differential equation (with differents intitial conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The two solutions correspond to different initial conditions. However two different conditions might correspond to the same solution. So care must be taken to pick suitable initial conditions for $f$ and $g$ (to be absolutely sure you need some existence and uniqueness theorem, that constrain how unregular your $a_i(t)$'s can be - in $a_0(t)x(t)+a_1(t)x'(t)+a_2(t)x''(t) = 0$).